# Excel Formula Assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

this is my first excel post ever so I hope you can help me on this. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to do this formula.

In here, I have Form Input where the start date, end date and outlet are logged by the user. Once this is logged, I need the value "x" to be populated next to each date that falls in the same date range selected by the user that matches the outlet name as well.

Is there any simple formula for this?

[image]

Edit: The input form is a list of dates range[Example 2][2] .. so If i click and drag using the formula, it should scan the full month in the dates range list and index "x" according to each date matched.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0qaT.jpg)

Comment: I see the 1/1/18, 7/1/18 & 8/1/18 dates are part of the form, but why there is no 'x' marks on the grid for those dates?

Comment: That's the point, I want the grid to automatically highlight any date mentioned in the form input with "x"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`=IF(AND(H6>$E$3,H6<$F$3),"X","")`

Paste that into the first cell where it is needed (I6 I believe) and copy the formula down by double-clicking on the fill handle:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did solve the problem but have just realized what if the first row of the date range does not match for Jan (Assuming the first row is Feb 2018), then the second row is Jan 2018 and the next could be Mar and April then back to Jan .. how can I tackle this formula where it will index the "x" where the date range matches the date range in the grid?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like you're describing a different situation than what was asked in your original question, please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1344580/edit) if that is the case.

Comment: I have just edited my post .. the formula you advised is superb if my form input is just two cells.. but the dates range are actually a list of dates (Start and End Dates) and the "x" should be indexed next to the date in the grid if it matches the date of the list

Comment: @AhmedBaksh, your current Screen Shot shows only two Date vales as Start & End. Modify & upload new Screen Shot with multiple Start & End dates to match with !! For current data you can use this one also,, `=IF(AND(H6:H13>=E$3,H6:H13<=F$3),"X","")`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .. I just added another screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In L3.. put this and drag downwards :

`=IF(OR(AND(K3>=$E$3,K3<=$F$3),AND(K3>=$E$4,K3<=$F$4),AND(K3>=$E$5,K3<=$F$5),AND(K3>=$E$6,K3<=$F$6),AND(K3>=$E$7,K3<=$F$7)),"x","")`

Done. Hope that helps. (:

*Note : If input data [FORM INPUT] is Sorted (earlier date 1st, then later dates) and 'Cleaned'(no overlapping date ranges). Then we can have a simpler way (that I can think.. ) of doing it. With what you have now.. this is the best that I can pull off for now..* 
( :